# Python Splinter Library ImportError: cannot import name Browser

Tags: python, splinter

I'm trying to use the Splinter library in python. When I use

```
from splinter import Browser
```

in the code it gives me:

File "D:\Users\User\Desktop\splinter.py", line 1, in 
ImportError: cannot import name Browser

I am trying to run the file from my desktop. Why is it looking on my desktop for splinter.py? There is no splinter.py on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: There was a file named 'splinter.pyc' on my desktop from before my file was named correctly. Deleting this fixed the problem.